# Matplotlib projection remove margin

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

Here's an image of US counties, created on top of

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.LambertConformal())
ax.set_extent([-120, -70, 20, 50], ccrs.Geodetic())
```

[image]

In the "live" figure one can see with `plt.show()`, there's a large gray area around the figure. Here you can (not) see it via the white padding.

So I thought I could zoom in a bit more:

```
ax.set_extent([-120, -70, 20, 40], ccrs.Geodetic())
```

And then this happened:

[image: cropped image]

While there is still white margin/padding around the figure, it's suddenly cropped. The "live image" also is showing me some white margin that is apparently placed around the projection.

I tried `plt.tight_layout()`, which indeed removed much of the margins, but left some (the second picture is taken after tightening the layout). This invisible margin makes it especially difficult to `ax.set_extent()`, as I can't see until where I can extend the map.

Is there some way to remove all the hidden padding/margin around the projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust):

To remove all the whitespace from around the `Axes` object, use:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)
```

Setting the `extent` is changing the data limits, not the position/size of the `Axes`.