# How to extract cartopy figure as numpy array and remove transparent borders?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am using cartopy to plot some part of the world, and try to extract the matplotlib figure as a numpy array made of the values of the figure's pixels. However, it seems that the figure is padded with some white borders (`[255 255 255   0]`) that I want to get rid of. How can I proceed?

Here is a sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

import io

MIN_LAT = 19
MAX_LAT = 53
MIN_LON = -20
MAX_LON = 41

# Map

fig = plt.figure()
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0)  

ax=plt.axes(projection=proj)

ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, color='lightgray')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)

# Select area
ax.set_extent([MIN_LON, MAX_LON, MIN_LAT, MAX_LAT], crs=proj)

io_buf = io.BytesIO()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
fig.savefig(io_buf, format='raw')
io_buf.seek(0)
img_arr = np.reshape(np.frombuffer(io_buf.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8),
                     newshape=(int(fig.bbox.bounds[3]), int(fig.bbox.bounds[2]), -1))
io_buf.close()

print(img_arr)
```

The displayed image is the below one:
[image]

The `img_arr` variable contains:

```
[[[255 255 255   0]
  [255 255 255   0]
  [255 255 255   0]
  ...
  [255 255 255   0]
  [255 255 255   0]
  [255 255 255   0]]
```

I expect the variable `img_array` containing only `[211, 211, 211, 255]` and `[151, 182, 225, 255]` values as they are values of pixels representing continents and oceans/seas in the above map.

Based on [this answer (Matplotlib projection remove margin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410665/matplotlib-projection-remove-margin), I tried to add this:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)
```

but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the extra white space is that [`figsave`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) adds its own margins (default is 0.1 inch) when saving the figure. You must override this default and also specify a bounding box to only save the axes contents, not the whole figure (which as a rule has an aspect ratio different than `(MAX_LAT-MIN_LAT)/(MAX_LON-MIN_LON)` and hence will contain extra white space on top/bottom or on the sides. You can just use `'tight'` here.
The new array shape will then be derived not from the figure size but from the axes size.

```
io_buf = io.BytesIO()
b = ax.get_window_extent()
fig.savefig(io_buf, format='raw', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
io_buf.seek(0)
img_arr = np.reshape(np.frombuffer(io_buf.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8),
                     newshape=(int(b.height), int(b.width), -1))
io_buf.close()
```

The following output of `plt.imshow(img_arr)` shows the correct result without any margins:
[image]